# Instagram Photos in WPF C# Application

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, winforms, instagram

I need to show Instagram photos with description in my WPF Windows Application and I found [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/how-to-authenticate-and-get-data-using-instagram-api/) article with ASP.NET.

It works the same what I required. But I dono how to use in my WPF application. I tried the same code, but I don't Know what to give in parameter `redirect_uri` while registering for instagram as it was an WPF Windows Application. Kindly help me guys!

[image]

Comment: as name suggests `redirect_uri` may be for redirecting page when image gets clicked.

Comment: redirect_uri is the website link which we entered while registering application in instagram. Though im using WPF, the is no use of URL I feel.

Answer (score -1):

From the link you have posted redirect_uri is the URL in your application where the user, will be redirected after logging in . And the value is aquired from AppSetting key, And to configure the application/user settings in a WPF application this is a good article to start http://geekswithblogs.net/mbcrump/archive/2010/06/17/configuring-applicationuser-settings-in-wpf-the-easy-way.aspx

Comment: Is there any URL for windows applicaiton? I know to get the URL for Website. how to get for WPF WIndows applicaiton?

Comment: No, In windows application you will have to redirect to the form you want your users to go after they have been authenticated. Your initial question seemed to be like about Configuration Manger in wpf .